# Can I somehow identify the physical machine from inside an OpenVZ container?

Tags: proc, sysfs, openvz

I am using some VPSes in OpenVZ containers. As I can see, our hosting provider somes moves them between his physical machines. It also means unwaited (and unexpected) reboots.

I have no technical contact with the VPS provider (there is a... complex company structure ;-) ), but I would like to know, what is happening and why.

I checked the `/proc/cpuinfo`, yes it sometimes changes. But it is not enough.

Can I somehow extract some ID about the host machine, while I have only a root access to the VPS (and zero access to the host)?

Comment: As far as I remember openvz: only if the hosting provider has set something up that allows you to.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! I've tought on `rdtsc` to read the cpu cycles since the last poweron from the host cpu; and maybe somehow some cpuid is also available. I think the OpenVZ may have some intentional mechanism to avoid it, but it is not sure.